# ¿Cómo se envían los parámetros a firebase analytics en swift 5?

Tags: firebase, ios, swift, google-analytics

Estoy trabajando con firebase analytics con swift 5 e ios, veo que debo enviar los parámetros del evento de la siguiente forma:

```
Analytics.logEvent(event, parameters: [
      "image_name": "Boton2",
      "full_text": "Boton 2",
      "count" : Int.random(in: 0 ..< 10).description
    ])
```

Cuando hago lo anterior los parámetros del evento se reflejan en mi consola de firebase correctamente, sin embargo, cuando hago lo siguiente:

```
let dataAnalytics = [
      "image_name": "Boton2",
      "full_text": "Boton 2",
      "count" : Int.random(in: 0 ..< 10).description
    ]
    Analytics.logEvent(event, parameters:dataAnalytics)
```

La consola de firebase los ignora por completo. mi pregunta es ¿Qué formato deben llevar los parámetros del evento para que la consola los reconozca? pregunto esto ya que yo paso los parámetros a mi método así [String:String].
De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Leyendo [la doc de `logEvent()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Classes/Analytics#declaration), aparece que `parameters`   tiene que ser del tipo `[String : Any]`, entonces, si pruebas a declarar el objeto así debería funcionar: `let dataAnalytics: [String: Any] = [
      "image_name": "Boton2",
      "full_text": "Boton 2",
      "count" : Int.random(in: 0 ..< 10).description
    ]` ...Mi anterior comentario se refería a otro tipo de escenario...

Comment: Justo así lo tengo, y no me funciona si lo paso como variable, tengo que pasarlo directo forzosamente, lo que me parece bastante burdo

Comment: Pero no lo tienes declarado así: `let dataAnalytics: [String: Any] ` no al menos en el código que muestras en la pregunta...

Comment: Comprueba que `dataAnalytics` está definida como `[String: Any]` eso es fundamental. Si no te funciona, prueba a pasarlo así:  `Analytics.logEvent(event, withParameters:dataAnalytics)`

Comment: Aquí está el método completo:


func initialize(event: String, params: [String:Any]){
        /*let dataAnalytics: [String:Any] = [
          "image_name": "Boton2",
          "full_text": "Boton 2",
          "count" : Int.random(in: 0 ..< 10).description
        ]*/
        Analytics.logEvent(event, parameters:  params)
    }

Comment: Acabo de probar con "Analytics.logEvent(event, withParameters:dataAnalytics)" y me da error: Incorrect argument label in call (have '_:withParameters:', expected '_:parameters:')

Comment: Al final estás pasando `params`, no el objeto `dataAnalytics`, debería ser: `Analytics.logEvent(event, parameters:dataAnalytics)` y el bloque se ve comentado con `/*  */`... ¿?

Comment: El método debería quedar así: **`func initialize(event: String, params: [String:Any]){ 
 let dataAnalytics: [String:Any] = [ "image_name": "Boton2", "full_text": "Boton 2", "count" : Int.random(in: 0 ..< 10).description ] 
 Analytics.logEvent(event, parameters: dataAnalytics) }`** aunque no entiendo por qué declaras los parámetros dentro de la función `initialize` y al mismo tiempo son un argumento de la misma.

Comment: Perdón, modifiqué el código, así quedaría el método al final: 
func initialize(event: String, params: [String:Any]){
        Analytics.logEvent(event, parameters: params)
    }

Comment: ¿Sigue sin funcionar? Pulsa en [edit]  y pon como tienes el código ahora, incluyendo el contexto donde creas los parámetros y haces la llamada del método.